# Want to get the content from the database as link to the menu items, where the menu items are called using AngularJs( ng-repeat) dynamically

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to add a link to the menu items which are called from the database dynamically using AngularJs.

Please check my code then only you will understand What I'm struggling.

There is no way to give it directly add links using `<href>`.

So far I have successfully completed the fetching menu and sub menus dynamically from the database and it is displaying without any error.

Here I am showing my code, please check:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>Assets/js/angular_app.js" ></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js" >
</script>

<script 
type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Assets/css/angularmenu.css" />  


</head>

<div ng-app="menuApp">
<div ng-controller="menuController">
     <div id="wrapper1" class="container">
       <div id="nav1">
       <div><span></span> </div>
             <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" ng-class="{'has-children': (menu.post_title ==='News')}" ng-click="changeClass(menu)" >


                  <a>{{menu.post_title}}</a>

                  <ul ng-if="menu && (menu.post_title ==='News')" ng-controller="subController">

                   <li ng-repeat="submenu in submenus" class="has-children" ng-controller="subController">


                      <a href="{{submenu.post_content}}">{{submenu.post_title}}<span ></span></a></a>

                          <ul ng-if="submenu" ng-class="submenu.class">
                          <li ng-repeat="subsubmenu in submenu.menus">

                              <a href="#">{{subsubmenu.title}}</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                    </li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

#### app. js

```
var app = angular.module('menuApp', []);

  app.controller("menuController", function($scope,$http)
  {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/samplepage/';
    $http.get(baseUrl+'Home/getmenu').then(function(response)
    {    
    console.log(response);
    $scope.menus = response.data;
});

});

  app.controller("subController", function($scope,$http)
  {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/samplepage/';
    $http.get(baseUrl+ 'Home/getsubmenu').then(function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.submenus = response.data;
    });
  });
```

### RESULT

[image: The result]

The problem needs to add links to all these menu items how is it possible using angularJs.

I've searched for weeks already and don't seem to progress any further. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use router link and also get links from database like you are getting menu.

Comment: @Sayed Mohd Ali   Thank you so much for responding.                                                                                               If my code was like this -                                                                               
 <li><a routerLink="home">Home</a></li>                                                         
  <li><a routerLink="about">About</a></li> .Then it is easy to add the link , but I get all the menu items here -$scope.menus = response .data, here i get all the parent menu items, That what im struggling , hw vl i give links to all the menu items.

Comment: Any suggestions please

Comment: get links from database and with ng-repeat you can get links.

<td><a href="#/quote/{{val.id}}" >{{val.title}}</a></td>

Comment: Thank you for your response .. I get menu items and links through ng-repeat but the problem is how can i add those links properly to the each menu items .

Comment: val.id have all the links  and val.title have all the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `routerLink` instead of `href`,

```html
<!-- Exemple -->

<li ng-repeat="subsubmenu in submenu.menus">
  <a [routerLink]="subsubmenu.link">{{subsubmenu.title}}</a>
</li>
```

I hope it will help you.